# Scala/Spark XML Ingestion: Column value coming as part of XML data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have an XML coming from a source having column information in XML tags
For example:

```
<root>
<item>001</item>
<attribute_type>Name</attribute>
<attribute_value>ABC</attribute_value>
<attribute_type>address</attribute>
<attribute_value>XYZ</attribute_value>
</root>
```

The output should be like this:

```
Item | Name  | Address
001  | ABC   | XYZ
```

I think this is not specific to Spark framework only.
Eventually I want to push this data to an HDFS.

Any suggestions?